# Here Maps API Location Address

Tags: geocoding, here-api

Here Maps: I originally used this code to get the address on a category search but now address seems to have been removed and replaced with a vicinity property in HTML.  Is this correct and is there a way to gain this level of detail?

```
if (locations[i].address.house != undefined) { 
  catResults2 = catResults2 +  locations[i].address.house + " " 
}
if (locations[i].address.street != undefined) {
  catResults2 = catResults2 +  locations[i].address.street
}
if (locations[i].address.district != undefined) { 
  catResults2 = catResults2 +  ", " + locations[i].address.district
}
if (locations[i].address.city != undefined) { 
  catResults2 = catResults2 +  ", " + locations[i].address.city
}
if (locations[i].address.state != undefined) { 
  catResults2 = catResults2 +  ", " +  locations[i].address.state
} 
if (locations[i].address.postalCode != undefined) {
   catResults2 = catResults2 + " " + locations[i].address.postalCode
}
if (locations[i].address.country != undefined) { 
  catResults2 = catResults2 +  ", " +  locations[i].address.country
}  
if (locations[i].address.countryCode != undefined) { 
  catResults2 = catResults2 + " " +   locations[i].address.countryCode
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are reverse geocoding the address of a location using the HERE Maps API for JavaScript (as in this example [here](http://developer.here.com/apiexplorer/examples/api-for-js/places-search/reverse-geocode.html)), then a properly localized address can be obtained using

```
locations[i].address.text
```